# Different position of indices after parentheses of the same height

Tags: math-mode, boxes

Let us look at the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\left(y-y_0\right)^2-(x-x_0)^2}{\left((x-x_0)^2+\left(y-y_0\right)^2\right)\displaystyle\mathstrut^2}.
\]


\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

The parentheses made by `(...)` and `\left(...\right)` are of the same height, but the position of `2` is different. Why?
Moreover, `\mathstrut` should have the same height as parenthesis, but the position of `2` is yet another. Why?

Comment: Have you tried using \Bigl ?

Comment: @Sebastiano I can obtain different sizes of parentheses. The problem is: why the same size gives 3 different heights of indices?

Comment: I think that the problem Is the fraction. My upvoted there Is ☺️

Comment: @Sebastiano: But the problem occurs also in the numerator.

Comment: Use `\left(` and `\right)` throughout, to see the effect: `\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\left( y - y_0 \right)^2 - \left( x - x_0 \right)^2}{\left( \left(x - x_0 \right)^2 + \left( y - y_0 \right)^2 \right)^2}.\]`. And remove the strut and display command, for the moment. It's introducing height.

Comment: @MarianG. Dearest Marian, I had not seen the numerator at all. I focused on the denominator. However, my assumption of using \Bigl( or \Bigr) and affine was correct.

Answer (score 8):

`\mathstrut` has the same height as a *normal size* parenthesis and you're basically setting the last exponent to an empty subformula, because `\vphantom{...}` doesn't make a math atom.

You get the same output with

```
$\Bigg)\vphantom)^2$\par
$\Bigg)\vphantom{\Bigg)})^2$
```

namely

[image]

In order to set a superscript to a `\right` delimiter, you need to have nothing between the delimiter and the exponent.

This almost settles the denominator. What about the numerator? The construction `\left<delimiter>...\right<delimiter>` builds a subformula, so TeX takes into account the full height when deciding for the placement of the superscript.

More simply,

```
\[
\left(y_0\right)^2\ne (y_0)^2
\]
\[
\left(y_0\right)_2\ne (y_0)_2
\]
```

[image]

This also explains why the denominator has oversized parentheses.

So you have discovered a rather good example why `\left` and `\right` should be used with great care. Choose among the following two examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} =
\frac{(y-y_0)^2-(x-x_0)^2}
     {\bigl((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\bigr)^2}.
\]

\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} =
\frac{(y-y_0)^2-(x-x_0)^2}
     {((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)^2}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have little doubts about the second one being better and clearer.

Answer (score 3):

`\left\right` has spacing effects even when it doesn't select a larger delimiter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} =
\frac{(y-y_0)^2-(x-x_0)^2}
{\bigl((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\bigr)^2}.
\]


\end{document}
```

If you add `\showoutput` to your original and look at the ) in the numerator the first ) using `\right` is

```
.........\hbox(7.5+2.5)x3.8889
..........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
```

The second one does not have the surrounding box

```
........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
```